# Maximizing one number in a set of 37, given parameters

Tags: combinatorics

> There are 37 contestants in a competition, each of them has a non-negative integer score.
> Given that the sum of any 17 contestants' scores is bigger than or equal to 45, and the total score of 37 contestants is 150.
> Find the maximum score one contestant can get.

Maximizing one contestant should mean minimizing the others, given the total score is constant.

However, we also have a limit of 17 contestants' score sum need to be at least 45.

$45\div17=2...11$

So everyone need to be at least 3, if everyone has 3 points except for one, then that contestant would have 42 points, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:**$\;$Subject to the specified restrictions, the maximum possible individual score is $48$.

**Proof:**

Let $m$ be the maximum possible individual score, subject to the specified restrictions.

Note that an individual score of $48$ can be realized using

- $3$ scores equal to $1$.

  $33$ scores equal to $3$.

  $1$ score equal to $48$.

Hence $m\ge 48$.

To show $m=48$, we can argue as follows . . .

Suppose we have scores $0\le x_1\le\cdots\le x_{37}=m$

Let $a=x_1+\cdots +x_{16}$.

Necessarily $a+x_{36}=45$, else, without breaking the specified conditions, we could decrease $x_{36}$ by $1$ and increase $x_{37}$ by $1$, contradiction.

It follows that $a+x_n=45$ for all $n\in\{17,...,36\}$.

Consequently we have $x_{17}=\cdots =x_{36}$.

If $x_{36}\le 2$, then $a+x_{36}\le 17{\,\cdot\,}2 < 45$, contradiction.

If $x_{36}\ge 4$, then
\begin{align*}
x_1+\cdots +x_{36}
&=
(a+x_{17})+(x_{18}+\cdots +x_{36})
\\[4pt]
&=
45+(x_{18}+\cdots +x_{36})
\\[4pt]
&\ge
45+19{\,\cdot\,}4
\\[4pt]
&=
121
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
but that would imply $x_{37}\le 150-121=29$, contrary to $m\ge 48$.

Therefore we must have $x_{36}=3$, so
\begin{align*}
x_1+\cdots +x_{36}
&=
(a+x_{17})+(x_{18}+\cdots +x_{36})
\\[4pt]
&=
45+19{\,\cdot\,}3
\\[4pt]
&=
102
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $m=x_{37}=150-102=48$, as claimed.